# Why does a block 2 on a oscillating block 1 start sliding at the maximum acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, acceleration, oscillators

A block of mass  $ m_{1} $ is oscillating horizontally with another block on it of mass $ m_{2} $. There's friction "k" between both blocks, so the thing is why the second mass starts sliding at the maximum acceleration of the first block. Is it a probabilistic thing?

Comment: Is the "plank" in the title the same as the $m_1$ block of the text?  By "both surfaces" do you mean between $m_1$ and the surface beneath it as well as between $m_1$ and $m_2$?

Comment: Thanks. I already corrected it. You are right. Regarding the second point, I meant friction only between $ m_{1} $ and $ m_{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block would not necessarily start sliding at the maximum acceleration of $m_1$, but rather as soon as the acceleration exceeds $\mu\,g$, because at that point, the force required to accelerate it would exceed the maximum frictional force.

If you want to simply check if the block will start sliding, then you can compare the maximum acceleration to $\mu\,g$ because if the maximum acceleration does not exceed this value, then the block would not slide at all.

Comment: Thanks man. I misunderstood the problem. The fact was that I was asked to find the maximum amplitude for the second block not to starts sliding. That's why they were looking for the maximum aceleration. Anyway, you have clarified many of my doubts. :D

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is probabilistic in (Newtonian)physics as far as I know. I think it starts sliding when the inertial force of m2 exceeds the force of friction k.

Comment: How about quantum physics? Please do read about that and its most common interpretation(s)...

Comment: @Martin I think sliding blocks would come under Newtonian physics?

Comment: Yes, but "nothing is probabilistic in physics" is a statement more general - and false in its generality.